# MAMP - Accessing wp-admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mamp, wp-admin

I am learning WordPress and I have had a terrible time getting back into `localhost:8888/wp-admin/`. It worked fine when I first built the site, but I was unable to access the wp-admin log in screen after I turned my laptop back on. The login screen comes on occasionally, but goes back to the error page when I try to log in. When I type in `localhost:8888/wp-admin/`, I go to a screen with this message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect. Search Google for localhost 8888 admin
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My MAMP settings:

```
Apache Port - 80
Nginx Port - 80
MySQL Port - 3306
```

Comment: You have Apache and Nginx both running simultaneously and listening on the same port?

Comment: Use either apache or nginx! Port 80 means the standard, so you access without any port number eg. http://localhost/wp-admin/

Comment: Thanks - logging in through localhost/wp-admin worked.